# PATCH method to MongoDB using Node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to create a PATCH method for my API but there is something I don't understand. Imagine I have the following document in my `MongoDB` database:

```
{
    _id  : ObjectId(1234...),
    name : "bob",
    age  : 30
}
```

Now I would like to update this document but I don't know what `keys` my API will receive. So imagine I make a `request` in order to change the `age` but also add a `last_name`.

The request result would be like this:

```
{
    _id  : ObjectId(1234...),
    name : "bob",
    last_name : "smith",
    age  : 44
}
```

The main problem here is that I don't know the arguments I will receive.

My goal is to update the values of the existing keys and **add the keys that are not in the document.**

Any idea?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You want to use the `$set` operator.

What this does is only updates the keys that are sent in the update query. Without `$set`, it will overwrite the whole object, which is obviously not what you want.

```
app.patch('/user/:id', function (req, res) {
    var updateObject = req.body; // {last_name : "smith", age: 44}
    var id = req.params.id;
    db.users.update({_id  : ObjectId(id)}, {$set: updateObject});
});
```

I'm assuming a couple things here:

1. You are using express.
2. You are using either the mongodb driver or mongojs npm module

Comment: This is how I approach this also, but was wondering if you had since found a way around $set. Clearly it works, so I'm really just curious about a clever solution.

Comment: @Vontei I think another way you could do is to get the existing object from the DB, do a comparison manually, then push the whole object without $set. That could be good for schema validation, but I just like using $set with the proper schema validation. It's lightweight, and can be used with the $ operator on arrays of the matching query.

Comment: This is basically how I do my post requests, so I don't need PUT or PATCH anymore as a POST does all three.

Comment: This isn't working for me. Patch is overwriting the whole document! @Brian Noah